# Teamcity modifies my own assembly by adding DataOnStack struct

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, teamcity

To ensure coding standards I have a couple of unit test which uses reflection to see that nothing is wrong. One of those looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void All_structs_should_be_immutable()
{
    var mutableStructs = typeof (Product).Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(type =>
                type.IsValueType && !type.IsCompilerGenerated() &&
                !type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).All(
                field => field.IsInitOnly))
        .OrderBy(type => type.FullName);

    foreach (var mutableStruct in mutableStructs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mutableStruct.FullName);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual("", string.Join(", ", mutableStructs.Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray()));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, mutableStructs.Count());
}
```

The Product class is within my own assembly which has nothing to do with Jetbrains/Teamcity.

This works fine when running the tests with Resharper. But when I run it in Teamcity, I get this error:

> Test(s) failed.   Expected string length 0 but was 51. Strings differ at index 0.
>
> Expected:
>
> But was:  "JetBrains.Profiler.Core.Instrumentation.DataOnStack"
>
> -----------^
>
> at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
>
> at NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)
>
> at Litium.Kamakura.UnitTest.CodingStandards.ImmutableStructs.All_structs_should_be_immutable() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\99395abb82d2a3b3\Test\Litium.Kamakura.UnitTest\CodingStandards\ImmutableStructs.cs:line 26
>
> ------- Stdout: -------
>
> JetBrains.Profiler.Core.Instrumentation.DataOnStack

How and why does Teamcity modify my assembly?

Comment: doest your mutable struct collection actually fills with data, or it remains empty?

Comment: It has one type in it. The "JetBrains.Profiler.Core.Instrumentation.DataOnStack" struct is in it.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with TeamCity 6.5.  I am only looking for classes though, so by using type.IsClass, i was able to filter out the TeamCity structure, DataOnStack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems as Teamcity's test runner (NUnit test runner?) was configured to run with dotCover / dotTrace. One of the profilers above has edited your code (remember that they are .net profilers, and they can inject code at JIT compile time, among others).

According to this [bug track](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/DCVR-3039?query=by), Jetbrains use this structure and will not remove it, so you will have to use a workaround.

See also [Teamcity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+.NET+Code+Coverage) - you can try running with a different runner, or collecting coverage with NCover, or disable coverage altogether.